# Showing T maps X to X

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let X be the space of continuous functions from $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$ to itself with the uniform metric.  Let T be such that

$$T(f(x))=\int_0^x3t^2+(f(t))^2dt$$

Show T maps X to X.

I simply just tried to integrate the value, so I would get $$x^3+\int_0^x(f(t))^2dt$$

And I don't know how  to integrate this.  I know that $x^3$ is continuous and bounded by $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ for all x in the same interval, and I believe I have to argue that the integral I have left is continuous.  Can I assume that the square of a continuous function is itself continuous, thus continuous functions are integrable hence it is integrable in $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$ so the the original integral can be viewed as maps in there?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is clear that if $f$ is continuous, then $f^{2}$ is also continuous, as composite of continuous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Calculate the derivative of T(f(x)) and show that it is an increasing function, T(f(0))=0 and $T(f(1/2))\leq 1/2$ you can estimate T(f(1)) since
$\int_0^{1/2}f^2(t)dt\leq\int_0^{1/2}1/4 dt$ since $f(t)\in [0,1/2]$.

Comment: This answer has been extremely useful and helpful, just one quick clarification; do you mean $T(f(1/2))\leq 1/2$?  I just want to be 100% sure although I believe you mean that, thank you